# Delphi: AnimateWindow like in FireFox

Tags: delphi, firefox, animation, window, animatewindow

I have a panel (bottom aligned) and some controls (client aligned).

To animate the panel I use:

```
AnimateWindow(Panel.Handle, 1000, aw_hide or AW_SLIDE OR AW_VER_POSITIVE);
panel.Visible:=false;
```

In my case the panel smoothly hides and only then other controls take it's space.

But I want that other controls move smoothly and simultaneously with the panel down.

For example, FireFox uses this effect.

Can anybody suggest me something useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnimateWindow` is a synchronous function, it will not return until the animation finishes. That means during the time specified in `dwTime` parameter, no alignment code will run and your 'alClient' aligned controls will stay still until the animation finishes.

I'd suggest to use a timer instead. Just an example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FPanelHeight: Integer;
    FPanelVisible: Boolean;
..

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPanelHeight := Panel1.Height;
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Interval := 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
  FPanelVisible := not FPanelVisible;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  Diff: array [Boolean] of Integer = (-1, 1);
begin
  Panel1.Height := Panel1.Height - Diff[FPanelVisible];
  Panel1.Visible := Panel1.Height > 0;
  Timer1.Enabled := (Panel1.Height > 0) and (Panel1.Height < FPanelHeight);
end;
```

Comment: you forget application.proccessmessage inside timer1timer.

Comment: @Roro - You don't need ProcessMessages in an OnTimer. Once the timer event handler returns, the application will continue to process messages.

Comment: oh good thats good input for me because i never know that, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Delete the second line

```
AnimateWindow(Panel.Handle, 1000, aw_hide or AW_SLIDE OR AW_VER_POSITIVE);
panel.Visible:=false;
```

and leave only

```
 AnimateWindow(Panel.Handle, 1000, aw_hide or AW_SLIDE OR AW_VER_POSITIVE);
```