# Image slide effect. BitBlt shimmers

Tags: delphi

I want to create a slide effect: one bitmap is painted from right to left on a form's canvas. For this I use BitBlt.

I call this function in a Timer (20ms):

```
var ViewPort: TRect;
ViewPort.Left   := 0;
ViewPort.Top    := 0;
ViewPort.Width  := 1400;
ViewPort.Height := 900;

x: integer := spnStep.Value;  //SpinBox.Value = 10
```

---

```
procedure TfrmTester.Slide(BMP: TBitmap; ViewPort: TRect);
begin
 Inc(x, spnStep.Value);

 if x >= ViewPort.Width then
  begin
   x:= ViewPort.Width;
   Timer.Enabled:= FALSE;
  end;

 BitBlt(frmTester.Canvas.Handle,
        ViewPort.Width-x, 0,    //  X, Y
        x, ViewPort.Height,     // cX, cY
      BMP.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
end;
```

However, the image does not progress smoothly. It has some kind of flicker, but not the kind of flicker that we know in the VCL. It is difficult to describe it. It is like the image moves two pixels forward and then one pixel backward.

How to make the image move smoothly?
Could the actually be caused by the refresh rate of the monitor?

---

Update: I don't know why, but it is caused by the timer.
If I call Slide() in a 'for' loop then the animation is smooth.
I know that the timer has an accuracy of ~15ms, but I still don't get it why it makes the image to shimmer.
If I add a sleed(1) inside the loop the shimmer effect appears again, and it is even worse. It really looks like the image is drawn twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should only paint on the form in the form's `OnPaint` handler. I don't know if you do that or not, but you should do so.

Second, you cannot really rely on the temporal distance between successive `WM_TIMER` messages being very precise or even constant. So it is better to check the actual time each time you paint. For instance, you may use the formula `Position = Original Position + Velocity × Time` known from school physics.

Also, to avoid flickering, you should probably handle `WM_ERASEBKGND`.

Putting these together,

```pascal
unit AnimatedRabbit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRabbit: TBitmap;
    FStartTime: TDateTime;
  const
    Speed = -100;
    function GetRabbitLeft: Double;
  protected
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  public

  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses
  DateUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRabbit := TBitmap.Create;
  FRabbit.LoadFromFile('K:\rabbit.bmp');
  FStartTime := Now;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FRabbit);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := Round(GetRabbitLeft);
  BitBlt(
    Canvas.Handle,
    x,
    0,
    FRabbit.Width,
    FRabbit.Height,
    FRabbit.Canvas.Handle,
    0,
    0,
    SRCCOPY
  );
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  if x > 0 then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, x - 1, ClientHeight));
  if x + FRabbit.Width < ClientWidth then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(x + FRabbit.Width, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight));
end;

function TMainForm.GetRabbitLeft: Double;
begin
  Result := ClientWidth + Speed * SecondSpan(Now, FStartTime);
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
  if GetRabbitLeft + FRabbit.Width < 0 then
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

end.
```

<del>I think this is as good as you can make it using GDI (a graphics API from the 1980s). I bet it will look better in Direct2D (or OpenGL, if you prefer that).</del>

## Update

After further investigation, I suspect that the usual timer isn't good enough. The problem is two-fold: (1) The best FPS obtainable by a normal timer is too low. (2) The fact that the duration between two consecutive `WM_TIMER` messages isn't constant causes visual issues.

If I instead use a high-resolution [multimedia timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers), ignoring the fact that they are deprecated, I get a nicer result:

```pascal
unit AnimatedRabbit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

const
  WM_DOINVALIDATE = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRabbit: TBitmap;
    FStartTime: TDateTime;
    FMMEvent: Cardinal;
  const
    Speed = -100;
    function GetRabbitLeft: Double;
  protected
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMDoInvalidate(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DOINVALIDATE;
  public

  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses
  DateUtils, MMSystem, Math;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure RepaintFunc(wTimerID: UINT; msg: UINT; dwUser: NativeUINT;
  dw1, dw2: NativeUINT); stdcall;
begin
  PostMessage(MainForm.Handle, WM_DOINVALIDATE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  TargetResolution = 1;
var
  tc: TTimeCaps;
  res: Cardinal;
begin
  FRabbit := TBitmap.Create;
  FRabbit.LoadFromFile('K:\rabbit.bmp');
  FStartTime := Now;
  if timeGetDevCaps(@tc, SizeOf(tc)) <> TIMERR_NOERROR then
    Exit;
  res := EnsureRange(TargetResolution, tc.wPeriodMin, tc.wPeriodMax);
  if timeBeginPeriod(res) <> TIMERR_NOERROR then
    Exit;
  FMMEvent := timeSetEvent(10, res, RepaintFunc, 0, TIME_PERIODIC);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timeKillEvent(FMMEvent);
  FreeAndNil(FRabbit);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := Round(GetRabbitLeft);
  BitBlt(
    Canvas.Handle,
    x,
    0,
    FRabbit.Width,
    FRabbit.Height,
    FRabbit.Canvas.Handle,
    0,
    0,
    SRCCOPY
  );
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  if x > 0 then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, x - 1, ClientHeight));
  if x + FRabbit.Width < ClientWidth then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(x + FRabbit.Width, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight));
end;

function TMainForm.GetRabbitLeft: Double;
begin
  Result := ClientWidth + Speed * SecondSpan(Now, FStartTime);
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMDoInvalidate(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

end.
```

## Update 2

And here is the non-deprecated version:

```pascal
unit AnimatedRabbit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

const
  WM_DOINVALIDATE = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRabbit: TBitmap;
    FStartTime: TDateTime;
    FTimer: THandle;
  const
    Speed = -100;
    function GetRabbitLeft: Double;
  protected
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMDoInvalidate(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DOINVALIDATE;
  public

  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses
  DateUtils, Math;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure RepaintFunc(Context: Pointer; Success: Boolean); stdcall;
begin
  PostMessage(MainForm.Handle, WM_DOINVALIDATE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRabbit := TBitmap.Create;
  FRabbit.LoadFromFile('K:\rabbit.bmp');
  FStartTime := Now;
  if not CreateTimerQueueTimer(FTimer, 0, RepaintFunc, nil, 0, 10, 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteTimerQueueTimer(0, FTimer, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  FreeAndNil(FRabbit);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Integer;
begin
  x := Round(GetRabbitLeft);
  BitBlt(
    Canvas.Handle,
    x,
    0,
    FRabbit.Width,
    FRabbit.Height,
    FRabbit.Canvas.Handle,
    0,
    0,
    SRCCOPY
  );
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  if x > 0 then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, x - 1, ClientHeight));
  if x + FRabbit.Width < ClientWidth then
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect(x + FRabbit.Width, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight));
end;

function TMainForm.GetRabbitLeft: Double;
begin
  Result := ClientWidth + Speed * SecondSpan(Now, FStartTime);
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMDoInvalidate(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

end.
```

Also, I previously said that the precise result depends on CPU, GPU, OS, and monitor. But it also depends on the eye and brain. The thing that makes this animation require such a high-quality timer is the fact that the motion is a simple translation with constant velocity, and the eye + brain can easily spot any imperfection. If we had animated a bouncing ball or SHM, an old-school timer would have been enough.

Comment: meh.... your example is as almost as choppy as mine. I guess, you are right.... maybe cannot be done smoothly without Direct2D.

Comment: @Z80: Please try to run the code; I realise that the MP4 added a lot of "flickering". The MP4 is bad, it looks better in reality. It also looks marginally better in Direct2D, I just tried it.

Comment: Yes. I ran your example. No modifications, expect of a bigger picture (1400x900px). It is quite similar to what I see in the video.

Comment: It might also depend on your CPU, GPU, OS, etc.

Comment: I looked better at the "shimmering" effect (your and mine). It looks like parts of the image are moved forwards, but some parts are not... at least not immediately.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at your new code tonight.

Comment: PS: I think it can be done also with GetTickCount instead of hires timer.

Comment: @Z80: No. You need the system to invoke your refreshing code regularly. Hence, you need a timer that sends you `WM_TIMER` messages, or a timer that invokes a procedure of your choice regularly. `GetTickCount` only tells you the current time. It won't make any code execute!

Comment: @adreas- Yes, but one could use a loop instead of a timer and wait in the loop. But instead of sleep one could use GetTickCount. Of course this will freeze the program. I need my slide effect to be 1-second longs. I think I afford to freeze the program for 1 second. But don't get me wrong. I don't disagree with you. The timer is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be drawing on the Form's `Canvas` from outside of its `OnPaint` event **at all**.  All of the drawing should be in the `OnPaint` event only.  Have your timer save the desired information into variables that the Form can access, and then `Invalidate()` the Form, and let its `OnPaint` event draw the image using the latest saved information.

Alternatively, simply display your `BMP` inside a `TImage` control, and then have the timer set that control's `Left`/`Top`/`Width`/`Height` properties as needed.  Let the `TImage` handle the drawing of the image for you.

Comment: So, my Slide procedure should be inside OnPain, and then in the timer I call MyForm.Invalidate?

Comment: "*my Slide procedure should be inside OnPain*" - no. It should save the provided parameters, and any calcaluted values as needed, to variables that the `OnPaint` handler can access. "*and then in the timer I call MyForm.Invalidate?*" - yes.

Comment: @Z80: The `BitBlt` should definitely be in `OnPaint`. What Remy is trying to say is probably that the things before the `BitBlt` in your `Slide` shouldn't be in `OnPaint` (but in the timer, for instance).

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I was thinking at the main painting function (BitBlt) which is in Slide. I shouldn't have use "Slide" in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AnimateWindow`

Here's the DFM. Just add client aligned `TPicture` inside the `TPanel`

```
object Form30: TForm30
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form30'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 389
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 389
    Height = 289
    Align = alTop
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clRed
    FullRepaint = False
    ParentBackground = False
    ShowCaption = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Visible = False
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 136
    Top = 304
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

And the Button1.OnClick handler:

```
procedure TForm30.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    AnimateWindow(Panel1.Handle, 1000, AW_SLIDE or AW_HOR_POSITIVE or AW_ACTIVATE);
end;
```

Comment: got it: Winapi.Windows.AnimateWindow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625201/delphi-animatewindow-like-in-firefox

Comment: that flickers like hell!!

Comment: This is also synchronous -- that is, you block the GUI thread during the animation. You shouldn't do that for even half a second. (What if the user tries to move or resize the window? Minimize or restore? What if Windows decides that the app is not responding and replaces its window with a white ghost window?)

Comment: It doesn't flicker at all on my side with image 1400x900. Make sure to set TPanel.FullRepaint to False, and form DoubleBuffered to True.
@AndreasRejbrand: Delphi's TSplitView is asynchronous? No.

Comment: @dwrbudr: Yes, `TSplitView`'s methods return immediately and use a timer to do the animation! But even if that control had been badly designed, that wouldn't mean that it is OK to do so!